# How to Capture text from DB column in SQL Server 2012?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

[image]I have a column `notes` with a length of more than 80,0000 characters.

As per the transformation rule, I have to write a SQL script which will caption the notes column in the below steps :

- First 300 characters in `Column_A`
- Next 300 characters in `Column_B`
- Next 300 characters in `Column_C`

and so on.

So I am looking for a output as below :

[image]

For every client ID with end of the length of the notes column.

Comment: Where is your code! what have u tried so far?

Comment: This is not very clear. You have an exact 3 columns and then as many rows as it takes? This is an extremely ugly thing you are doing to your data here.

Comment: Here's my script :   WHEN CN.Note IS NOT NULL AND CN.Note <> ''   THEN LEFT(ISNULL(CN.NOTE, SPACE(1)), 100) END 'SCATEXT',
   CASE WHEN CN.Note IS NOT NULL AND CN.Note <> ''   THEN  SUBSTRING(ISNULL(CN.NOTE, SPACE(1)), 101, 300)  END 'SCATEXT1',
   CASE WHEN CN.Note IS NOT NULL AND CN.Note <> ''   THEN  SUBSTRING(ISNULL(CN.NOTE, SPACE(1)), 301, 500)  END 'SCATEXT2',   
   CASE  WHEN CN.Note IS NOT NULL AND CN.Note <> ''   THEN  SUBSTRING(ISNULL(CN.NOTE, SPACE(1)), 501, 700)  END 'SCATEXT3'

Comment: @SeanLange :  I have one column notes with a length of more than 80,0000 characters and I need to split 80,0000 into 3 other columns with len of 300 characters. Each time a new time stamp will be generated for 300 characters...yeah I know it's messy, but I hope you will understand it.

Comment: How exactly do you propose to fit 80,000 characters into 3 columns of 300 characters each? Or does it need to split across those columns and take up 89 rows? And what could possibly be a real world situation for this?

Comment: I have a notes Columns for a DB field and I am transforming the data into 3 different columns in a new system. New system will have 3 columns, with max length of 300 char. But I need to split 80,000 char into 3 columns using SQL, there will be multiple rows for each column.

Comment: So this is a one time data export process? Sounds like the new system is going to be painful to work with. :( Now that I understand what you are trying I should be able to throw something together.

Comment: I only have basic knowledge of SQL, this logic is far away from my understanding.

Comment: @Peter, you didn't get an answer because your question is unclear. You say you have a column Notes with 80,0000. Is this column in another table? How many rows with 80000 chars are there? Etc. Elaborate on this, show some example of what you are trying to achieve, for example on 20 chars that you will split across 3 columns by  4 chars. What about clients? Should splitting reset from begining of that 80000 column when client changes? If there are 5 rows with 800000 strings then what happens?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri I have just uploaded an image may b that will ans your qus

Comment: @Peter, does each customer has its own 80000 string?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri there are more than 10000 CustomerID and each customerid has more than 50, 000 characters..Suppose  as a customer I have a loan account..and there is a agent from XYZ company calls me after the discussion he will add (save) the conversation summary in the Notes column with a TIMESTAMP and everytime he will call he will save the notes..thus there are few customers having the account more than 10 years old that's why the data is massive..NOTE : Each client will be saved with a TIMESTAMP...

Comment: I've added a possible solution below.  Apologies for the complexity but shredding values into multiple rows and columns requires a little bit of SQL magic.

Comment: @destination-data, Thank you  I will also trying to making some amendments in my script using your logic.

Comment: @Peter did this work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Ouch!  That's quite a complex requirement.  You will need to combine a number of skills to solve this one.

Firstly you need to create additional rows.  One way to achieve this is via [recursion](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx). In the example below I've calculated how many rows are required for each Client Id.  I've then used recursion to create them.

You also need to break each row into 3 300 character blocks.  In my example I've used 3 3 character blocks instead, so it's easier to read.  But the principle will scale up.  Using [SUBSTRING](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) and the record number you can calculate the starting point for each column.

I've created some sample records in a [CTE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175972.aspx) called Raw.  This allows anyone to follow the example, which is up on Stack Data Exchange (link below).

[Example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/409330/splitting-text-in-multiple-rows-and-columns)

```
DECLARE @ColumnWidth   INT = 3;       -- Use to adjust required length of columns A, B and C.
DECLARE @ColumnCount   INT = 3;       -- Use to adjust number of output columns. 


WITH [Raw] AS 
    (
        /* This CTE creates sample records for us to experiment with.
         * The note column contains each letter of the alphabet, repeated 
         * 3 times.  The repeatition will help us validate the result set.
         *
         * Using ceiling, to round up, the field length (@ColumnWidth) and 
         * the number of fields (@ColumnCount) and the number of charaters (LEN) 
         * we can calculate how many rows are required.
         */
        SELECT
            r.ClientId,
            r.Note,
            CEILING(CAST(LEN(r.Note) AS DECIMAL(18, 8)) / (@ColumnWidth * @ColumnCount))    AS RecordsRequired
        FROM
            (
                VALUES
                    (1, 'aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnooopppqqqrrrssstttuuuvvvwwwxxxyyyzz'),
                    (2, 'aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklll'),
                    (3, 'aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnno'),
                    (4, 'aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjjkkklllmmmnnnoooppp'),
                    (5, 'aaabbbcccdddeeefffggghhhiiijjj'),
                    (6, 'aaabbbcccdd')
            ) AS r(ClientId, Note)
    ),
    MultiRow AS
    (
            /* This CTE uses recursion to return multiple rows for 
             * each orginal row.
             * The number returned matches the RecordsRequired value
             * from the Raw CTE.
             */
            SELECT
                1 AS RecordNumber,
                RecordsRequired,
                ClientId,
                Note
            FROM    
                [Raw]

        UNION ALL 

            -- Keep repeating each record until the number of required rows has been returned.
            SELECT
                RecordNumber + 1 AS RecordNumber,
                RecordsRequired,
                ClientId,
                Note
            FROM    
                MultiRow
            WHERE
                RecordNumber < RecordsRequired

    )
/* Each record returned by the MultiRow CTE is numbered: 1, 2, 3 etc.
 * Using this we can extract blocks of text from the orginal Note column.
 */
SELECT
    ClientId,
    SUBSTRING(Note, ((@ColumnWidth * @ColumnCount) * RecordNumber) - ((@ColumnWidth * 3) -1), @ColumnWidth)    AS Column_A,
    SUBSTRING(Note, ((@ColumnWidth * @ColumnCount) * RecordNumber) - ((@ColumnWidth * 2) -1), @ColumnWidth)    AS Column_B,
    SUBSTRING(Note, ((@ColumnWidth * @ColumnCount) * RecordNumber) - ((@ColumnWidth * 1) -1), @ColumnWidth)    AS Column_C
FROM
    MultiRow
ORDER BY
    ClientId, RecordNumber
;
```

Comment: Yes, I have successfully made changes in the scripts..thank you for help..Really Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this:

```
DECLARE @c TABLE(ID INT, Notes VARCHAR(26))
INSERT INTO @c VALUES
(1, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'),
(2, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')

DECLARE @size INT = 26
DECLARE @chunk INT = 5

;WITH tally AS(SELECT 1 s1, @chunk + 1 s2, 2*@chunk + 1 s3
               UNION ALL
               SELECT s3 + @chunk, s3 + 2*@chunk, s3 + 3*@chunk FROM tally
               WHERE s3 < @size)
SELECT c.ID, 
       SUBSTRING(Notes, t.s1, @chunk) A, 
       SUBSTRING(Notes, t.s2, @chunk) B, 
       SUBSTRING(Notes, t.s3, @chunk) C
FROM @c c
CROSS JOIN tally t
ORDER BY c.ID, t.s1
```

Output:

```
ID  A       B       C
1   abcde   fghij   klmno
1   pqrst   uvwxy   z
2   ABCDE   FGHIJ   KLMNO
2   PQRST   UVWXY   Z
```

Description:

tally table returns you the starting positions, which you will use in `substring` function. For the above configuration it returns:

```
s1  s2  s3
1   6   11
16  21  26
```

For this you are using recursive cte which spreads starting positions across the rows with 3 starting position. The rest should be easy to understand.

Comment: I have tried a solution using recursive CTE but i was getting a max recursion error.couldn't troubleshoot that.Thats why i go with the looping method

Comment: @mindbdev, you could set an option `FROM @c c
CROSS JOIN tally t
ORDER BY c.ID, t.s1
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)`

Comment: Thank u very much.I knew that we can use 0 for that but i couldn't recollect.dont know how i missed  it when i did this.Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

The required result can be obtained using simple looping

```
/* Declare a temperory table for storing the results */
    DECLARE @Result_TABLE AS TABLE
    (   
     CustomerId     BIGINT
    ,ColA           VARCHAR(300)
    ,ColB           VARCHAR(300)
    ,ColC           VARCHAR(300)
    )

    DECLARE @CustomerCount INT      --To store customer count
    DECLARE @IteratorForCustomers INT = 1 --To iterate for each customers
    /* Get Count of cutomers */
    SELECT @CustomerCount = COUNT (1) FROM Customers 

    DECLARE @CustomerId BIGINT  --To store customer id in looping
    DECLARE @TempNote VARCHAR(MAX) -- To store customer note of each customer in looping
    /* Loop for all customers */
    WHILE (@IteratorForCustomers <=@CustomerCount)
    BEGIN
        ;WITH CTE AS
        (
        SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerID ) AS RowId
        ,CustomerId
        ,Customer_Note
        FROM Customers
        )
        SELECT
          @CustomerId = a.CustomerId
         ,@TempNote = a.Customer_Note
        FROM CTE a
        WHERE 
        RowId = @IteratorForCustomers

        /* Loop for generating each row with three columns */
        WHILE (LEN(@TempNote)>0)
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @Result_TABLE 
            VALUES 

            (
            @CustomerId,SUBSTRING(@TempNote,1,300),SUBSTRING(@TempNote,301,300),SUBSTRING(@TempNote,601,300)
            )

            SET @TempNote = CASE WHEN LEN(@TempNote)>900 THEN   SUBSTRING(@TempNote,901,LEN(@TempNote)-900)
                            ELSE NULL END


        END

        SET @IteratorForCustomers = @IteratorForCustomers + 1

    END

    SELECT * FROM @Result_TABLE
```

Comment: I have slightly modified my query in the same way..It also has a performance improvement.